# MongoDB in Android studio

Tags: java, mongodb, connection

It's three days i'm trying to connect an Android 6.0 app to an ATLAS mongodb Database
this is the connection settings:

```
     String ConnectionString = "mongodb://" + UserName +":" + Password + "@" +
            "xxxxxxxxxxx-00-00.8yajj.mongodb.net:27017,"+
            "xxxxxxxxxxx-00-01.8yajj.mongodb.net:27017," +
            "xxxxxxxxxxx-00-02.8yajj.mongodb.net:27017/" +
            "?ssl=true";
        ConnectionString _connectionString = new  ConnectionString(ConnectionString);
        MongoClient _client = MongoClients.create(_connectionString);
        MongoDatabase _database = _client.getDatabase(DbName);
        MongoCollection _collection = _database.getCollection(CollectionName);

        Document sampleDoc = new Document("_id","1").append("name","Caccola Pelosa");
        _collection.insertOne(sampleDoc);
```

What's is wrong ?
i'm trying to use SCRAM authentication and X.509.........not working at all !!!!
any help will be appreciate

Comment: I guess you have this problem not only in Android studio (at least if you try), if so, please don't post unrelated details to the title of question. Also the title should contain error description for example error message as well as error message should be part of question. So please update the question.

Comment: as for the question, atlas provides a guide how to connect to your application. `Databases` -> `Connect` -> `Connect your application` -> `Select your driver and version` (java + version) -> `Add your connection string into your application code` -> check `Include full driver code example`

Comment: you should also make sure that firewall (and similar) is not in play on your side as well as `Network Access` is properly configured on atlas side

Comment: also, I would recommend using `mongodb+srv` connection string form